# How to replicate the whole redis cluster

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, replication

Now we deploy redis clusters in IDC1 and IDC2. The servers in IDC1 will only access the redis cluster in IDC1 and so does IDC2. We hope IDC1 and IDC2 could replicate for each other with the final consistency.

We know about the replication of redis instance and we use twemproxy for one cluster now. How can we replicate the whole redis cluster in different IDCs.

Comment: each CLUSTER has its own Master/Slave setup right? You want to do a UNION of data between IDC1 and IDC2?

Comment: anyway if you want to different masters in the same mega-cluster you probably need to use http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec or build your own solution of propagation.

Comment: Thanks @bitoiu I think we use redis as an import storage system in the wrong way. We want two IDCs have all the same data and we care don't care about the replication of instances. There's no way to it now.

Comment: well, you say you don't care about replication, but in the end you'll have two exact similar instances. I would first try to use one master to do all the writing, and leave that approach if performance is a problem. until you prove it is, there's nothing you can do.